# How do you solve these two examples? I'm having some trouble

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac{1-7x}{x^2-5x+6}\,dx$$
$$\int\frac{x-1}{x^3+x^2}\,dx$$
I've been trying for like an hour to no avail. Can somebody solve them step-by-step so I can correct what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: partial fractions. And did you try them in that one hour?

Comment: I think I've tried that, probably still made a mistake

Comment: Factorise the denominator, and then express the numerator as a linear combination of those factors

Comment: Have you see this site (https://www.integral-calculator.com/)? For things like this its pretty helpfull

Comment: Thanks to you both! I'll try

Answer (score 1):

The partial fraction decompositions of the two integrands are as follows:
$$\frac{1-7x}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{13}{x-2}-\frac{20}{x-3}$$
$$\frac{x-1}{x^3+x^2}=\frac2x-\frac1{x^2}-\frac2{x+1}$$
Now you can just apply standard integration formulas to each component and sum them up.

Comment: That makes sense, i'll try it. Thanks